# Magento display more products on home than the limit

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I want to show all the images from category 10 on the home page, which number is 24, but the limit of the site is set to 15. How can I set it to All only for the home page?

This is the block code:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="10" template="catalog/product/list_home.phtml"}}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try this - Go to system > configuration > catalog > frontend. You can configure your catalog limits here.

Or this - If that doesn't work, make sure that this value is not hard-coded on any of the XML layout files in your theme folder.

One thing to point out is that by doing this, you will heavily increase your loadtime since you have to not only query the data, but also create additional server calls.

I suggest that you get a free account with CloudFlare so alleviate the load on the page.

System > Configuration > Catalog > Frontend :

[image: system > configuration > catalog > frontend]